# Adding Row with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to add a row that calculate the difference in percentage from the last two row.

This is my code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=DAU, columns=['Q', 'DAU'])
dfm = pd.DataFrame(data=MAU, columns=['Q', 'MAU'])

df['o_cat'] = pd.Categorical(df['Q'], Quarter_Order, ordered=True)
dfm['o_cat'] = pd.Categorical(dfm['Q'], Quarter_Order, ordered=True)

df = df.sort_values('o_cat')
dfm = dfm.sort_values('o_cat')

df = df[['Q', 'DAU']]
df['MAU'] = dfm[['MAU']]

print df
```

This is the result :

[image]

And i want to add this row at the end:

```
5  ,    %  ,   0.41   ,   50
```

Comment: You can do this but you should be aware you're violating the tabular nature of the dataframe.  That is, you're attempting to add a record with entirely different schema to the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.concat` with `axis = 0` to bind them together:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'Q': '%','DAU': 0.41,'MAU': 50}, index=[5])], axis = 0)
```

Comment: And how do i put a calculation for 0.41 and 50, I want it to be the division of the the rows before ?